# GitHub synchronization is not mirroring my visual studio 2019 project's files and folder structure

Tags: github, visual-studio-2019

I have a Github master branch problem.  I'm the only developer using a particular project repository.  That said, I do all work using new branches to commit changes and push to the remote tracked branch.  My question is, when I'm done with a feature push to remote and perform the pull request with approval for merge, the remote does not delete files nor folders from earlier pull request.  How do you do this without manually deleting files and folders on GitHub.com?

Just to be clear, I am using Visual Studio 2019 for source control to GitHub.  I had performed an initial commit, push to remote, pull request and approved/merged the branch into Master...some of those files need to be deleted.  My Visual Studio has the files/folders that I want the Github repo master to look like.

Comment: As a follow up, inside the visual studio 2019 solution the folder ViewModels is no longer under the Resume project...it's been moved to its own project, but the Github repo shows ViewModels folder (and class files) in the original place from a prior commit...hope this clears it up a bit

Comment: What do the folders on your local machine look like?  Folders in the Solution Explorer in VS are merely logical containers, not actual folders on disk.

Comment: I'm new to StackOverflow, but am a seasoned web, software and database programmer.  The issue is I had created a ViewModels folder in VS and committed to the repository in the beginning of the project...now that the project is done, that folder is no longer on my Visual Studio project/solution....it's been moved into it's own Class Library project in the same solution....but Github has ViewModels in both the original place and the new place

Comment: Does the folder still exist on disk but excluded from your project?  Can you trace the Git history for the rename and make sure the files were moved and not copied?